# Activerecord reads UUID as an Integer. I need the actual UUID as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, uuid

I am trying to save a filename with the same name as the hash of the corresponding record.

Currently the data importer is using rails, but the database and corresponding schema, were generated outside of the application.

When I read the `Account` model in `psql` I see:

`select * from accounts where id=1`

```
id                     | 1
first_name             | JOHN
middle_name            |
last_name              | DOE
suffix                 |
dob                    | 1985-11-29 00:00:00
gender                 | M             
hash                   | 5062a455-ad6e-4104-ae49-92d12b1fbd27
```

when I use ActiveRecord I get the following:
`Account.first`

```
id: 1,
first_name: "JOHN",
middle_name: "",
last_name: "DOE",
dob: Fri, 29 Nov 1985 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
gender: "M",
hash: "5062a455-ad6e-4104-ae49-92d12b1fbd27"
```

When I try to access the hash using `Account.first.hash` I get `-1029718433662254257` instead of `"5062a455-ad6e-4104-ae49-92d12b1fbd27"`.

I essentially want to do `filename = "#{account.hash}.png"` but now all of my file names are negative numbers instead of the UUIDs.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hash` is a method on the base `Object` in Ruby. Nothing you can do about that really* except change the name of the field in your db. https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/hash

> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have
>   the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash. The hash value
>   is used by class Hash. Any hash value that exceeds the capacity of a
>   Fixnum will be truncated before being used.

---

As suggested in the comments you can also access it directly with

```
# in your view or model
account[:hash]
```

Comment: Yeah, one definitely must not mess with built-in `hash` method. It's a terrible name here anyway. A UUID is not a hash.